# Set KNITRO honorbnds option through JuMP, Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I am trying to use KNITRO thought JuMP. And I also like to set the option `honorbnds = 2`, which implies that the bounds are enforced only for the initial points. But how should I specify the bounds for the parameters? It seems that the bounds though JuMP's `set_lower_bounds/set_upper_bounds` function are enforced for all proposed solutions but not just the initial values.

Comment: I'm guessing you already looked at [this](https://github.com/jump-dev/KNITRO.jl#mathoptinterface-interface) ?

Comment: Thanks @MarcMush! I have looked that, and I have figured out the problem, I misunderstood the meaning of honorbnds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`honorbnds` only applies to the initial point. Variable bounds are enforced in the final solution. If you don't want the bounds enforced, don't add them.